# How to hide questions with given title?

Tags: support

Dear Gaming Stackexchange community,

In previous stackexchanges (SO, SU, etc) I usually found my daily dose of altruism by browsing &clicking around interesting tags, hot questions, etc. However, due to high popularity of Starcraft 2, this method of mine fails miserably on Gaming SE -almost every other question is starcraft-related.

So, is there any way I can hide questions marked with specific tags? Or should I just abandon the splash / hot section altogether?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the `[starcraft-2]` tags to your ignored tags, will fade out the questions marked with that tag, which allows you to easily ignore them, just like on any other stack exchange.

Comment: thanks for the timely response :)

Comment: @Silver Dragon, You might want to accept the answer from @Oak, as it is more complete.

Answer (score 10):

If you add the [starcraft-2] tag to your *ignored tags*, all questions tagged with [starcraft-2] will appear shaded.

You can also make these questions disappear completely by doing to your profile page, choosing the "prefs" tab, then making sure the "Hide Ignored Tags" option is checked.